# Filtering Datatables by Slider Values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've got a datatables table working great and now I'd like to add an additional element. The user can move a slider to select a range, click search, and the table returns only those rows with a specific column value within the range.

Here's the script for the filtering:

```
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('.leftLabel').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('.rightLabel').val(), 10 );
    var score = parseFloat( data[11] ) || 0; 

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && score <= max ) ||
         ( min <= score  && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= score   && score <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
 );
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider_search').click(function () {
var table = $('#total_datatable').DataTable();
    table.draw(); 
} );
});
```

And here's the script to originally draw the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#total_datatable").DataTable({
 "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {

    "url":"compare_2.php",
    "type":"GET"
 }  ,


   "paging":        true, 

   "pageLength": 100,
 "order": [[ 10, "asc" ],[11,"desc"],[1,"asc"]],
  "aoColumns": [
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "0%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Provider ID" },
 { "bSortable": true,  "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Hospital Name" },
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2",  "sTitle": "Address","visible":false    },
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "City" },
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "State",},
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "ZIP Code"},
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "County","visible":false  },
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "0%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Phone","visible":false },
 { "bSortable": true,  "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Condition"},
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2",  "sTitle": "Measure ID"},
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "Measure Name" },
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Score",},
 { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Sample"},
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "Footnote","visible":false  },
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Measure  Start","visible":false },
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%", "sClass": "lang_body_2", "sTitle": "Measure End","visible":false },
  { "bSortable": true, "width": "20%","sClass": "lang_body_2","sTitle": "Index","visible":false  },

  ],
  "sDom": 'f<"clear">rtip',

});

});
```

The slider values are populated in here:

```
<div class="leftLabel" style="display:inline-block;"></div>  
<div class="rightLabel" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
```

What should happen is that after you select the slider values and click the #slider_search button, the table should redraw with the same settings as the original table, but filtered to the specific rows. I've used this [range filtering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) before and my script is based off of this. I tried doing it with input boxes like the Datatables example and it works, but I want it to work based on the slider values and only when the user clicks search (the example updates the table as soon as you input).

So, the question is: What am I doing wrong that's causing this not to work in the manner that I'm looking for?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to do a client-side search but using server-side data.  I wouldn't have thought this was possible but seeing as you managed to do it with the input boxes, I might be wrong!

Comment: this is definitely possible as we use it everyday. About implementing sliders make sure you are sending/writing the data appropriately and then read by the plugin so it can attach the appropriate variables in the get request